# What is difference between if(c == 10) and if(c & 10) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I saw if condition like this if(c & 10) and This condition similar to this if(c==10). This is a correct way to write code in javascript?

Comment: a *comparison* and a *bitwise and* are two completely different operators.

Comment: I think `c & 10` will be truthy if C is a number and its "2" bit or "8" bit is set, and falsey (0) otherwise

Answer (score 3):

It's correct (as in, it's not a syntax error), but `&` and `==` are different operators.

`&` is the [bitwise AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_AND)) operator. `==` is the [abstract (loose) equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality) operator.

The reason `c & 10` and `c == 10` happen to work in an `if` when `c` is `10` is due to the fact that `c & 10` returns a truthy value (indeed, `10`); `c == 10` returns `true` (which is by definition truthy).

However, `c & 10` would also work for a large number of other integers, unlike `c == 10`.

Answer (score 0):

`c & 10` will produce a number.
`c == 10` will produce a binary value.

```js
var c = 10;
console.log("c & 10  = ",c & 10);    // 10
console.log("c &  7  = ",c &  7);    // 2
console.log("3 & c   = ",3 & c);      // 2
console.log("10 & 10 = ", 10 & 10); // 10
console.log("c==10 = ", c==10);     // true
```

Answer (score 0):

The *Bitwise AND* operator uses the binary representation of two integers and compares the binary digits (0 or 1) bit by bit and will produce a new integer with the responding bits set to 1 if and only if those corresponding bits in the first two numbers are both 1, otherwise that bit will be 0.

## Ex. 1

compare 10 and 20
10 is binary 00001010 = 8 + 2 = 2**3 + 2**1
20 is binary 00010100 = 16 + 4 = 2**4 + 2**2

#### Comparison

```
  00001010
& 00010100
  -------- 
  00000000
```

because at no bit position there are two 1s

## Ex. 2

compare 10 and 200
10 is binary 00001010 = 8 + 2 = 2**3 + 2**1
20 is binary 11001000 = 128 + 64 + 8 = 2**7 + 2**6 + 2**3

#### Comparison

```
  00001010
& 11001000
  -------- 
  00001000
      ^Here are two 1s
```

because at bit position 3 there are two 1s. So 200 & 10 are 8